# Upgrade SAM CLI in Cloud9

Tags: python, cloud9-ide, cloud9, aws-sam-cli, aws-cloud9

I'm using Cloud9 as my IDE for building lambdas in python.  Everything was working great.

But now when I run my lambda locally I get an error

```
A newer version of the AWS SAM CLI is available!
Your version:   0.2.11
Latest version: 0.31.0
```

Ok, so I tried upgrading by pip installing aws-sam-cli and it ran succesfully, telling me

> Successfully installed...aws-sam-cli-0.31.0

But my little previously working function continues being unable to load and generating the same error.

How do I get this upgrade to stick?

**Extra info**
If I slim my lambda call to just a pandas call using a sqlalchemy engine
- `df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)`- , it generates the error.  If I comment out that one line, it'll run the various print commands and execute without error.

Comment: fwiw, I followed this tutorial and  it worked: https://jun711.github.io/aws/steps-to-update-aws-cloud9-sam-cli-to-latest-version/

Answer (score 0):

Verify your system is pointing to the correct version

> sam --version

Update the symlink for Cloud9

> ln -sf $(which sam) ~/.c9/bin/sam